# Modifying a main method to take a text file when compiling the java file

Tags: java

How can I make a main method take a text file as an argument on the command line?

So for example

java ClassWithMainMethod textFileNeededInMainMethod.txt

I've been told this is possible but I'm not sure how it's done.

Comment: You would get all of the command line argument Strings in the main method's `String[] args` String array parameter. You should be able to find this information in most any intro to Java tutorial.

Comment: So args[0] in this case?

Comment: Yep, test it and see. But do read the tutorials or an intro to Java book.

Answer (score 1):

You use the `String[] args` from the Java program [entry point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point#Java) like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  if (args.length < 1) {
    System.err.println("no file provided");
    System.exit(1);
  }
  File f = new File(args[0]);
  // ...
}
```

That `if` could be used to set a default file if one isn't provided. Finally, it's a good idea to use [`File.canRead()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#canRead%28%29) before you try and read from a file.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments passed to main are of type `string` so you'd pass the name of the file or path of the file and then create a file object and then read its content.

You can't pass the type `file` to a java main class

Answer (score 0):

In your main method, the `args` array contains any arguments. For example, if you typed `java ClassWithMainMethod textFileNeededInMainMethod.txt`, then you could read the argument like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String file = "";
    if(args.length > 0) file = args[0];
}
```